# Estou tentando executar o codigo mas ele diz que quero converter uma str para float ,mas nao entendo quando dei esse comando

Tags: python

```
peso=[]
while True:
    peso.append(float("Qual sua altura?"))
    peso.append(float("Quanto voce pesa?"))
    soma=peso[0]/(peso[1]**2)
    rr=input("Deseja continuar [S/N]? ")
    if rr=="N":
        if soma==18.5:
            print("Seu imc é 18.5 por tanto seu peso esta normal")
        elif soma>=25 or soma==29.5:
            print("seu imc é {} portanto voce esta com sobrepeso".format(soma))
        elif soma>=30 or soma==39.9:
            print("Seu imc é {} portanto voce esta com obesidade ".format(soma))
            break
print("os pesos e alturas cadastrados respectivamente foram {}".format(peso))
```

Comment: `float("Qual sua altura?")` - vc está tentando converter a string `"Qual sua altura?"` para `float`, mas como ela claramente não representa um número, dá erro. Provavelmente o que vc quer é `float(input("Qual sua altura?"))`

Comment: A verificação do IMC está errada, tem vários valores que não são contemplados (por exemplo, se o IMC for 20, não entra em nenhum `if`/`elif`). Teria que ser algo do tipo: https://ideone.com/egrT0u

Answer (score 0):

Identifiquei 2 problemas no seu código, o primeiro é que você não está capturando os dados do usuário com o `input()` para o envio dos mesmos a lista `peso`.

O seu código é :

```
peso.append(float("Qual sua altura?"))
```

O mais apropriado seria:

```
peso.append( float( input( 'Qual a sua altura ? ') )
```

Observe que houve a adição do `input()`, que captura um dado do tipo String e através do `float` o converte para um número quebrado/flutuante.

Vale ressaltar também que dar um espaçamento no seu código ajuda na visualização e consequentemente na resolução de possíveis problemas que possam ocorrer.

O próximo problema que você vai ter é a indentação do `break`. Indentação refere-se a distância entre seu código e a lateral esquerda do mesmo em simetria com todo o restante do conteúdo. O seu break está dentro de um `elif`, e ao executar o seu Loop `while` não vai quebrar a menos que este `elif`, o segundo no caso, seja executado, meu conselho é puxe ele para trás, na mesma linha do `elif` e independente de qual `elif` seja satisfeito seu programa vai parar quando o usuário escolher "N". Sei que isso pode ter sido apenas erro de digitação na hora de vir pra cá, mas é bom ficar atento, já tive muito trabalho no começo por não notar coisas pequenas assim.

Antes :

```
    elif soma>=30 or soma==39.9:
        print("Seu imc é {} portanto voce esta com obesidade ".format(soma))
        break
```

Depois :

```
    elif soma>=30 or soma==39.9:
        print("Seu imc é {} portanto voce esta com obesidade ".format(soma))
    
    break
```